# TV show set on an autonomous space ship on a collision course

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Years ago I binge watched a show on Netflix that I can no longer name or find. Set on a spaceship which is not piloted and in distress and on a collision course with stars and planets.

The crew can somehow sit in a chair and teleport home to earth but in someone else’s body on earth.

I’ve looked for years for this show. The show was filmed in Canada. (Credits would say that)

Comment: Sounds to me like Stargate: Universe.

Comment: Years of googling you solved it in less than an hour. Thank you very much! You’re awesome!

Comment: You're most welcome.  If you're sure this is the show you were remembering, you can accept my answer (below) by clicking on the tick mark.  Note that we generally recommend that you wait 24 hours before accepting an answer in case another better answer is posted.  Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 12):

You're remembering [Stargate: Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe).

- Set primarily on the fully automated (and previously uncrewed) Ancient spaceship *Destiny*, where a team of soldiers and scientists from Earth have been stranded.
- The arrival of the team results in a power crisis when *Destiny* attempts to provide life-support.  If I remember correctly, there are also other systems that are either out of order or in poor working order after millions of years of unattended operation, and other systems that the team simply do not know how to or are otherwise unable to operate.
- In episode 5, [*Light*,](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Light_(episode)) the *Destiny* is on a collision course with a star.
- There was a [long-range communications device](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Long-range_communication_device) that swapped people's minds around, although you may also be confusing this with the [interface chair](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Destiny_interface_chair).
- It was indeed [filmed in Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe#Writing_and_filming).